# Is it possible to report what buttons the user click in an Android app?

Tags: android, c++

Is it possible to log a string from native C++ Android app and see it in Google Play Console?

For example, UWP event logger allows an app to log arbitrary strings (event names) and see them in MS Developer Console using the following code:

```
Microsoft::Services::Store::Engagement::StoreServicesCustomEventLogger ^ eventLogger = Microsoft::Services::Store::Engagement::StoreServicesCustomEventLogger::GetDefault();

eventLogger->Log("the user pressed OK button");
```

is there something like this on Android?

There is

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "My Log", 1);
```

but it prints logs locally. I am asking about reporting to Google Play Console. It is not for debugging, but for collecting the statistics on what the user do with the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can logcat be used to log NDK code in Android? Or what are logging options from NDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149481/can-logcat-be-used-to-log-ndk-code-in-android-or-what-are-logging-options-from)

Comment: it is not the answer, it prints logs locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is thru the use of [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/). With it you can:

1. determine where your best visitors are located
2. visualize what people click the most
3. identify worst and best pages of your app
4. determine events such as user clicks
5. and a lot more...

Comment: this is the answer, at least for Java app https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/